# delete all the appends that i made with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a button which works with jquery and appends a `h5` tag, but i want to delete them all when i press the X or `cerrar` button, can some someone help me?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
/* $('$errorrut').css('visibility','hidden'); */
$('#searchCertification').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$('#newrut').val()) {
        $('#ruterror').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#newrut').css('border-color', 'darkred');
    } else {
        var bloque = '<h5>Título o habilitación profesional: </h5>';
        $(bloque).css({'border':'1px solid','padding':'5px'});
        $('#titulosProfesionales').append(bloque);
        $('#baseTitulo').css('visibility','visible');
    }

});
$('#cerrar').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#ruterror').css('visibility', 'visible') && $('#newrut').css('border-color', 'darkred')) {
        $('#ruterror').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('#newrut').css('border-color', '#d2d6de');
    }
  });
 });
```

Here's the html code where i append those `h5`

```
<div class="row pt-15">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default" id="baseTitulo" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                    <div class="panel-body" id="titulosProfesionales">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all h5 inside the container then use:
ʼ$('#titulosProfesionales').empty()ʼ

Comment: this works but how can i put a limit on the numbers of h5 created, i mean, i just want it to appear only one time and no more

Comment: What do you mean to appear only one Time? You can use some variable for example of name ʼcounterʼ and whenever you add, you increment value and you add only when this value equals 0... And you make this counter 0 when you empty your container

Comment: that's it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assign a unique class name to the added `<h5>`s and then remove them programmatically referencing the unique class name.

I can be more specific if you show more code. It is not clear where you add the `<h5>` tags.

Comment: but, how can i make that when you click on the search again doesnt appear another h5 with that unique class